# Degree of maps $\mu \colon \mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^r$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, projective-geometry, projective-space

In the book I am reading right now, it is defined that for a map $\mu \colon \mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^r$ the degree is the degree of the direct image cycle $\mu_{*}[\mathbb{P}^1]$. We are working over $\mathbb{C}$, so the homology of $\mathbb{P}^r$ is $H_n(\mathbb{P}^r)=\mathbb{Z}$ whenever $0\leq n\leq r$ and $n$ is even.

$[\mathbb{P}^1]$ is the fundamental class I believe, i.e. the generator of $H_2(\mathbb{P}^1)$. This is sent under the push forward to a class in $H_2(\mathbb{P}^r)$. Is then the degree just the number we get in $\mathbb{Z}$?

I wanted to explicitly calculate some degrees of specific maps. For example take $r=2$ and suppose $\mu\colon \mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$ is given by a degree three homogeneous polynomials, for example $\mu(a:b)=(a^3:b^3:ab^2)$. My problem is that I don't know how to explicitly compute the degree of such a map or in general when we have degree $d$ homogeneous polynomials.

Comment: You can use local degree and look at the number of preimages for regular values of your functions

Comment: @Spotty could you explain why this should give the degree as in the above definition with homology?

Comment: @Spotty: note that $r\not=1$.

Comment: At least for smooth functions you can use that, because of Sard's theorem you don't hit everything with $\mu$. Now the projective space without a point is homotopy equivalent to the projective space in dimension one smaller. The homotopy equivalence should be easy to write down. But then you can use the local degree argument for the composition.